# Many_Many Relationship Fails with Property "ClassName.RelationName" is not defined

Tags: yii

Basically, I want to build the relation between the tables 'cities' and 'images'. They both have an ID column which is constrained by a third table called cities_images. Here's the structure of the table in the middle:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities_images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cityId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imageId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `imageId` (`imageId`),
  KEY `cities_images_ibfk_2` (`cityId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

ALTER TABLE `cities_images`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `cities_images_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`cityId`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `cities_images_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`imageId`) REFERENCES `images` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I have two models that work with the cities and images tables.

Relation inside Cities.php:

```
'citiesImages' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'CitiesImages', 'cities_images(id,cityId)'),
```

Relation inside Images.php:

```
'citiesImages' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'CitiesImages', 'cities_images(id,imageId)'),
```

I am trying a test action inside CitiesController with the following content:

```
$cities = Cities::model()->findByPk(2);
var_dump($cities->images);exit;
```

But this results in an error:

> Property "Cities.images" is not defined.

Note that there is a city with ID=2 and there is a row in cities_images with cityId=2 and imageId=1. There is also a row in the images table with ID=1, so I don't see why I can't access the images associated with the given City.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just referencing the wrong name.  Should be:

```
$cities = Cities::model()->findByPk(2);
var_dump($cities->citiesImages);exit;
```

Because that is how it is setup in the Cities.php model.

UPDATE:

Right, you need to simply change the models to point to the right model:

Cities.php:

```
'citiesImages' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Images', 'cities_images(imageId,cityId)'),
```

Images.php:

```
'citiesImages' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Cities', 'cities_images(cityId,imageId)'),
```

Comment: This results in a PHP warning:
`include(CitiesImages.php) function.include failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Oh right.  You just need to change your model's relations now.  Check that and let me know if the query works.

Comment: You can also change the names to something different instead of citiesImages to make it less confusing.  Then you can do what you wanted to do in the first place: $cities->images.  You can do that if you change the name of the relationship in the model from 'citiesImages' to 'images' in the Cities.php model.  Same goes with Images.

Comment: After changing the relations to point to the other model, I started seeing an empty array when var_dump-ing $cities->cityImages. Even after using `Cities::model()->findAll()` instead of `findByPk()`.

Comment: Okay, that is good that it doesn't give you an error.  I think I missed just one thing and that is the correct ids in the models relationships.  See the edits to the answer above.  Basically cities_images(imageId,cityId).  Sorry I keep missing things.  :)

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. I can now var_dump and see the columns of Images from the Cities model.

Comment: So, since you are receiving an array from $cities->citiesImages, you need to simply foreach through the results and reference that attribute on the image object.  Like foreach ($cities->citiesImages as $image) { echo $image->file; }